# Using mediaplayer in a regular class

Tags: android

I am having some trouble using the android MediaPlayer in a non activity class, always a context error. Here is the bugged line:

```
MediaPlayer Shoot = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shot);
```

Now I know I cant use `this` in a service, but all the other stuff I tried kept giving bugs.

any suggestions?

Comment: Well technically you can use `this` in a `Service` as it extends `Context`. Have you tried `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` however?

Comment: Since my class is already extending thread, this is not possible. i have also tried to use getApplicationContext via an object of an Activity, but it failed as well.

Comment: Make a subclass of Application, call it MyApplication or something, put it in your Manifest. Then you may get context anywhere by calling `MyApplication.getApplicatonContext()`

Comment: If your class is extending thread, pass activity to its constructor while create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
try {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(1);
    if (afd != null) {
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```